# Why doesn't this C vector loop auto-vectorise?

Tags: c, vectorization, avx2

I am trying to optimise some code by use of AVX intrinsics. A very simple test case compiles but tells me that my loop was not vectorised for a number of reasons that I don't understand.

This is the full program, simple.c

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

int main(void)
{

  __m256 * x = (__m256 *) calloc(1024,sizeof(__m256));    

  for (int j=0;j<32;j++)
    x[j] = _mm256_set1_ps(1.); 

  return(0);
}
```

This is the command line:
gcc simple.c -O1 -fopenmp -ffast-math -lm -mavx2 -ftree-vectorize -fopt-info-vec-missed

This is the output:

- simple.c:11:3: note: not vectorized: unsupported data-type
- simple.c:11:3: note: can't determine vectorization factor.
- simple.c:6:5: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
- simple.c:11:3: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
- simple.c:6:5: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.
- simple.c:6:5: note: not vectorized: not enough data-refs in basic block.

I have gcc version 5.4.

Can anyone help me to interpret these messages and to understand what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already manually vectorizing with intrinsics, so there's nothing left for gcc to auto-vectorize.  This leads to uninteresting warnings, I assume from trying to auto-vectorize the intrinsic or the loop-counter increments.

I get good asm from gcc 5.3 ([on the Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-xc+-O3+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-pedantic+-Wextra+-march%3Dhaswell+-fopt-info-vec-missed',source:'%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%0Avoid+set_to_1(__m256+*+x)+%7B%0A++for+(int+j%3D0%3Bj%3C32%3Bj%2B%2B)%0A++++x%5Bj%5D+%3D+_mm256_set1_ps(1.)%3B+%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3)) if I don't do something silly like write a function that will optimize away, or try to compile it with only `-O1`.

```
#include <immintrin.h>

void set_to_1(__m256 * x) {
  for (int j=0;j<32;j++)
    x[j] = _mm256_set1_ps(1.); 
}

    push    rbp
    lea     rax, [rdi+1024]
    vmovaps ymm0, YMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
    mov     rbp, rsp
    push    r10                      # gcc is weird with r10 in functions with ymm vectors
.L2:                                 # this is the vector loop
    vmovaps YMMWORD PTR [rdi], ymm0
    add     rdi, 32
    cmp     rdi, rax
    jne     .L2
    vzeroupper
    pop     r10
    pop     rbp
    ret

.LC0:
    .long   1065353216
    ... repeated several times because gcc failed to use a vbroadcastss load or generate the constant on the fly
```

I do actually get nearly the same asm from `-O1`, but using `-O1` to not optimize things away isn't a good way to see what gcc will really do.

Comment: Is there a useful and verbose documentation that explains GCC's infos and warnings regarding auto-vectorizations? I found the output sometimes confusing.

Comment: @Jens: No idea; I always just look at the asm output to see what the compiler did.  In a complex function, single-stepping in a debugger can help find the main loop (among the noise of peeled prologue/epilogue unaligned iterations).

Comment: Thanks Peter. I assumed that these messages implied something was awry. Your answer and my experience so far suggest there is really no substitute for some familiarity with asm. Better to know this sooner rather than later.

Comment: @ghostofsandy: The warnings are maybe useful to help identify why a loop doesn't auto-vectorize when it's reasonable to think / hope that it should.  Or to identify regressions, when a change makes a loop no longer auto-vectorize.  But yeah, if you know asm well, they're just a signpost for which loops to look at.  If you barely know any, then they're a clue to look for `...ps` instructions (packed single) instead of only `...ss` (scalar single).  e.g. [`mulps`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MULPS.html)